# How can I check if my website appears correctly in mobil devices?

Tags: android, html, iphone, mobile, web

I am learning web design, and I can make basic web sites on Windows desktop. My question is, how can I check this site if it appears correctly in other devices like Android or iPhone. I want to see it from my website directory on device, not from a "html://www.example.com". I don't want to buy a domain name for now, because, I want to learn web designing first. Also, I don't have iPhone, I don't know what to do. How can I see my website from a mobile device, or a tablet, even I don't possess it?

Comment: The http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You could use chrome, open the developer tools, and click the little device icon in the top left corner. From there you can resize the browser to see how the site conforms. They also have presets for popular devices.

The other option is to view it on the device itself. The simplest way to do this is to serve the files locally on your computer using a simple local http server. Something like http-server for node is a very simple solution for this.  You would connect your computer and your phone to the same wifi... then run the server from the root directory of the project. Then from your phone, access the website by typing your computers local ip address into the address bar of the device you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mobile test tool such as

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool created by Google. It will also show you a preview of what it will look like on the phone. [LINK](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)